# Aws Amplify - Login activity / logged in devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, identity

Is there a way to list out all logged in devices/sessions, something similar to what instagram does or even just list out all the active sessions, with AWS amplify?

Answer (score 0):

You can track user sessions and interactions with Amplify Analytics. You set it up through the cli with `amplify add analytics`. More information can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/analytics/getting-started/q/platform/js/).